# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" at performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, unrecognized-selector

So i have a programatically added button in my View Controller. Because of this I have created a push segue directly from my root View Controller to the next one. Already embedded the navigation controller.

This is me setting up the button and adding it's target;

```
registerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[registerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushRegisterScreen) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This right here is the pushRegisterScreen;

```
- (void) pushRegisterScreen
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"registerSegue" sender:self];
}
```

But this throws this exception;

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RegisterScreen _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d70d70'
```

First day with Xcode yay!

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint. Open the breakpoint navigator and click on the `+` at the bottom left. (Navigators are located on the left side of the Xcode window).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've seen this error before when you've set the class of a view (probably your controller's main view) to a class that's not a subclass of UIView. Make sure that when you set the custom class of your controller (in the storyboard) that you've set it on the controller, not its view.

Comment: You are a life saver! I had accidentally set the class of BOTH the controller and view in Register Screen Scene to the RegisterScene class which was subclassed from the UIViewController.

Answer (score -1):

Did you actually set the identifier @"registerSegue" in your storyboard? To do this go to the view controller in question and click it, then go to the identity inspector (right panel) and give the view a name. If you have already done this then the problem is within another location.

Comment: I have set the `registerSegue` identifier for the `Push Segue from Welcome Screen` in the storyboard. Are you suggesting that I am to call the originating view that?

Comment: What does Push Segue from Welcome Screen mean? Do you have a segue that you created from the UIButton to another UIViewController in your storyboard?

Comment: I created the button programatically, it's not in the storyboard. So I had to create the segue from View Controller. Read the question.